# Why am I getting an exception after upgrating Spring Security version from 5 to 6?

Tags: spring, spring-security, migration

Migrated Spring Security from 5 to 6.0. Getting following Exception , I tried all possible solution but nothing worked out. Someone please help me.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.getAuthenticationManager()" is null
    at com.jmi.jabord.core.oauth.filter.AccessTokenAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AccessTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
```

I tried to add this in my Filter class extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
@Override
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

But nothing worked out for me.

Answer (score -1):

In security configuration class you can try to add this:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```